# How to make an wifi Password cracker with Apple Script

Tags: macos, applescript, nsapplescript

a friend forgot his wifi-Password and the Question is, how to crack the password with apple script! Is there an easy way to do it with a script? He doesn't want to reset his Wifi router...
Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: Are any of the computers already connected to the router?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Unless the router of your friend is like ten to fifteen years old, apple script can only enter a random code of characters and numbers, and even if you had the code you need it wouldn't work because the router won't accept any more guesses after a specific amount (normally about 10).